# .Net Core cookie will not be set

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-core-mvc

**In .Net Core MVC project:** I'm trying to set a simple cookie in the easiest way in my controller-action but can not get it to be persistent and show up in the browser.

**My code:**

```
public IActionResult IndexPost()
{
    var option = new CookieOptions();
    option.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60);
    Response.Cookies.Append(cookieName, "SomeCookieValue", option);
    return View();
}
```

But in the browser (Chrome) I can't see it or even read it with:

```
var cookieValue = Request.Cookies[cookieName];
```

*(`cookieName` is a variable set with name of the cookie)*

If using Chrome extension "EditThisCookie" I can set it manually to ensure that `Request.Cookies[cookieName]` actually works, so error is in the Append-cookie of my code somehow.

Comment: Have you checked Chrome's network tab in the developer options? You should see the IndexPost request setting the cookie header there.

Comment: I see the request but no, cookie is not included there...strange. So somehow my code Response.Cookies.Append(cookieName, "SomeCookieValue", option) have no effect on the response?!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Starting from ASP.NET Core 2.1, the templates include a GDPR compliant configuration of your `CookiePolicyOptions` in Startup.cs, namely:

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});
```

The `CheckConsentNeeded` option of `true` will prevent any non-essential cookies from being sent to the browser (no Set-Cookie header) without the user's explicit permission.

You can either change this behaviour, or mark your cookie as essential by setting the `IsEssential` property to `true` when creating it:

```
var options = new CookieOptions
{
    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60),
    IsEssential = true
};

Response.Cookies.Append("rudeCookie", "I don't need no user to tell me it's ok.", options);
```

Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/gdpr?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: Yeah, thanks! That worked! Strange I have not seen this anywhere in my search for answer.

Comment: Sorry, but if you have connection HTTPS that's works fine. in my test I thats was the correct way.

Comment: Perfect, This is what I was missing.

Comment: .NET yet again not following the principle of least surprise

Comment: ok so for me, it may have been a _combination_ of **this** and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials