# Cookies are not set in .NET6 WebApi application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cookies, .net-6.0

For some reason my cookies are not being set. I have tried several things, but my cookie never appears to be set when I check the Cookie storage in Chrome or Edge.

In my Startup.cs I have the following:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;

        // Also tried SameSiteMode.None
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax;
    });

    ... 
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseCors(options => options
            .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials());
        app.UseCookiePolicy(); // Breakpoint hits this code
    }

    ...
}
```

Then in my Controller Action I try to set the cookie:

```cs
public IActionResult Test()
{
    // Also tried different SameSiteMode options, non seem to work.
    // If I set a breakpoint, then it hits. So code gets executed.
    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("X-Blaat", "test", new CookieOptions { Expires = 
    DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(1), SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax, IsEssential = true});

    return Ok();
}
```

This Web API runs on `https://localhost:44365`. The endpoint lives on: `https://locahost:44365/api/test`.

I call this endpoint through a React application which runs on `http://localhost:3000`.

But for some reason my cookie never gets set. Eventhough I can debug through the code.

Anyone any idea why my cookie never gets written to the browser?

## Update

When I call the same endpoint through Swagger, then the cookies do get set.

For some reason they are not appearing when I call my Web API through my React application.

I suspect the issue is that it runs on a different port than my Web API. Is there anything I can try to solve this issue?

Comment: Refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52461278/633098  Simply put, if `options.CheckConsentNeeded` is set to `true`, then only essential cookies are sent to the browser. To override this, you can mark your cookie as essential with the `IsEssential` flag set to `true`.

Comment: @silkfire That's what I have set, as you can see in my code example.

Comment: Okay sorry missed that bit somehow. Does your browser report anything about blocking those cookies? What does the response look like?

Comment: I know it is quite old. What was the solution to the problem that you faced. I have a similar situation. Trying to understand what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already figure it out.
But the problem is that you are trying to set cookie from https to http.
If you remove in the program.cs the line `app.UseHttpsRedirection();`
And in your client use the http version of the api, should work)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your React app has `credentials: 'include'` when making the login request to the server.

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

> Unless `fetch()` is called with the `credentials` option set to `include`, `fetch()`:
>
> - won't send cookies in cross-origin requests
> - won't set any cookies sent back in cross-origin responses

Also make sure to always set `.AllowCredentials()` on the `CorsPolicyBuilder`, not just in development mode.